# VBA - Declaring and Setting Range with nested pre-declared variables (Runtime error '91':)

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

First time query here!

I want to define my data frame on an excel worksheet. However when I attempt to Set the Range, I get a Run-time 91 error.

```
Dim i As Long
Dim WSCount As Long
WSCount = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

For i = 1 To WSCount Step 1

Select Case Worksheets(i).Name

Case "Page1_1", "Page2_2", "Written", "Waived", "Earned"

Dim LR As Long
LR = Worksheets(i).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Dim LC As Long
LC = Worksheets(i).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Dim DataFrame As Range
**DataFrame = Worksheets(i).Range("A2").Resize(LR, LC)**

DataFrame.ClearContents


End Select

Next i
```

**Both LR and LC generate the correct answer.**

However when I attempt to declare Dataframe as a Range and then set Dataframe as per below, I get an error that I cannot figure out...

**"Run-time error '91':
Object variable or With block variable not set"**

Does anyone have any idea what the issue is?

Much appreciated in advance!

Arthur

Comment: Assuming you want to start at `A1` just use `Set Dataframe = Range("A1").Resive(LR, LC)` - nothing wrong with your method this just seems easier to follow. You also have unqualified objects there and are relying on `Active` objects which can sometimes be messy. Better to be explicit.

Comment: @urdearboy Regarding unqualified object; I want to Dataframe.clearcontents and then loop through worksheets with Select Case based on the worksheet name. In that way I think that I would need to retain objects activeworkbook and activesheet

Comment: Set the worksheets as you go

Comment: What line is giving the error? I suspect the issue is with your unqualified `Cells` object. The code you have here is not enough to know though. Share more of the relevant code...

Comment: Why are you using `Row + 1` and `Cells(2, LC)`? I mean `+ 1` and `2`?

Comment: You forgot to use the `Set` keyword: `Set DataFrame = Worksheets(i).Range("A2").Resize(LR - 1, LC)`.  And remove `+ 1`.

Answer (score 0):

### Data Frame

- To fully qualify a range in the way you're 'constructing' it, you have to do the following:

  ```
  Set DataFrame = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(LR, LC))
  ```
- To avoid the previous you can use the `With` statement which also allows you to easily change the worksheet just in one place.
- Note the dots (.) in front of `Range`, `Cells`, `Rows` and `Columns`.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub df()
    
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim LC As Long
    Dim Dataframe As Range
    
    With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        LC = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        ' Explicitly: note the '2'.
        Set Dataframe = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(LR, LC))
        ' Implicitly i.e. you have the full range incl. the headers:
        ' Define 'full' range.
        'Dim rng As Range
        'Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LR, LC))
        ' Resize and offset to exclude the headers.
        'Set Dataframe = rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    End With
    
    Dataframe.Select

End Sub
```

**EDIT**:

- This is how I would have written your code using a `For Each Next` loop and `Application.Match` with an array of worksheet names.
- This is not case sensitive like your `Select Case` version so I can have e.g. `WriTTeN` and the worksheet will still be found.
- The `Dataframe` variable is not needed.
- The `2` is indicating that the range will start with the second row preserving the headers.

**The Code**

```
Sub df2()
        
    Dim wsNames As Variant
    wsNames = Array("Page1_1", "Page2_2", "Written", "Waived", "Earned")
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim LC As Long
    
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, wsNames, 0)) Then
            LR = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            LC = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(LR, LC)).ClearContents
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works like a charm. Much appreciated, I have learned a lot from this!